# Trimming Toenails in sequence

Tags: halacha, minhag, nail-cutting

As a follow up to the question "[Rules for Cutting Nails](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/rules-for-cutting-nails)" it occurred to me that while we spoke about the idea of not trimming one's nails in sequence (as well as discussing the relevancy of lenient opinions to the particulars of the question) I do not recall whether there is any basis to be careful not to trim one's toenails in sequence? I intend on looking this up myself but wanted to ask first (and I'm not sure it is explicitly mentioned in the more obvious places).

Comment: I was trying to be a little less unpleasant in my choice of title. :)

Answer (score 5):

Sefer Taamei Haminhagim (see [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=14556&st=%u05d4%u05e6%u05e4%u05e8%u05e0%u05d9%u05dd), bottom of page) cites the Perishah and Eshel Avraham who assume that toenails have the same law as fingernails, with regard to burning the nails and with regard to washing afterward, respectively. It seems reasonable to say that they would also extend the out-of-sequence rule to toenails.

Answer (score 1):

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 72:14: Some are careful to not cut nails in sequence.

יש מקפידין שלא ליטול את הצפרנים כסדרן אלא בדילוג, דהיינו בימין מתחילין באצבע הסמוך לאגודל, והסימן: ב ד א ג ה, ובשמאל מתחילין אצבע הרביעי והסימן: ד ב ה ג א.

The Aruch Hashulchan in 260:6 writes that the Magen Avraham brings that the Ari z"l used to poke fun at those who were careful about this. Yet, it is worth being careful about it when possible.

וגם כתבו שכשנוטל צפרניו לא יטול אותן כסדרן, ויתחיל בשמאל בקמיצה ובימין באצבע, וסימן לזה דבהג''א בשמאל ובדאג''ה בימין, וכתבו שהאריז''ל לא הקפיד על זה והיה מלעיג על זה, (מג''א) ומכל מקום כדאי ליזהר לכתחלה. (שם) וכל אלו הדברים אין להם שום מקום בדין, ומאן דקפיד - קפיד, ודלא קפיד - לא קפיד.

Comment: Thank you Danny.  I think this belongs here: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/1118/rules-for-cutting-nails .  I think this question was whether the same exact discussion would apply to TOENAILS as it would to FINGERNAILS.