# What is the danger in cutting fingernails in order?

Tags: sources-mekorot, superstition, nail-cutting

The Ramo (OH 260:1) writes that one should not cut their fingernails in order; rather he should cut them by skipping neighboring nails and cycling through all the fingers.

וכשנוטל צפרניו לא יטול אותן כסדרן. ויתחיל בשמאל, בקמיצה; ובימין, באצבע. וסימן לזה: דבהג"א, בשמאלו; ובדאג"ה, בימין (אבודרהם וספר המוסר).‏

He cites the Avudraham, who writes that there really isn't a reason for this at all, but then he continues and says that he heard in the name of French rabbis that there is a danger to poverty, memory, and the death of children.

ושמעתי בשם חכמי צרפת ופרבינצה שהנוטל צפרניו כסדר קשה לעניות ולשכחה וקבור בנים

1) What is the source of this perceived danger? Medical knowledge? Folk superstition? Or something more kabalistic? Are other dangers cited for this behavior?

2) Are there earlier recorded sources for the danger?

3) Are there contemporary poskim (within the last century) who deal with this halacha?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that עניות in this context means poverty. not gonna edit without someone else's opinion backing me though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rules for Cutting Nails](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/rules-for-cutting-nails)

Comment: @Vram FWIW I agree with you.

Comment: agree also.............

Comment: @GershonGold the answers there don't really address this question

Comment: however the question is already asked - so it should be merged.

Comment: @GershonGold, that question's "What?" while this question's "Why?" two different, highly-related questions.

Answer (score 3):

I was told that its to distinguish from when a Tahara is done and the nails are cut in order.

Comment: Aren't you just begging the question?

Comment: What does that have to do with poverty and memory?

Comment: Were told by whom?