# Can a Jew cut a non-Jew's nails consecutively?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, nail-cutting

Can a Jew cut a non-Jew's nails consecutively? This would relate to a profession in which one trims nails such as podiatry, nursing, pedicurist etc.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1118/759 and of course http://stackoverflow.com/q/7769032/807090

Comment: @DoubleAA That Stack Overflow question is priceless

Comment: What about a Jew cutting a *different* Jew's nails consecutively?

Comment: The Arizal was not particular about the order If I remember correctly.

Comment: ...or having one's nails cut by a non-Jew?

Answer (score 2):

The source of not cutting nails consecutively can be traced to the Remo in Shulchan Aruch, Orach Chaim [260:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.260.1?vhe=Maginei_Eretz:_Shulchan_Aruch_Orach_Chaim,_Lemberg,_1893&lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en), in the name of the Abudraham:

> כְשֶׁנּוֹטֵל צִפָּרְנָיו לֹא יִטֹּל אוֹתָן כְּסִדְרָן. וְיַתְחִיל בִּשְׂמֹאל,  בַּקְּמִיצָה; וּבְיָמִין, בָּאֶצְבַּע. וְסִימָן לָזֶה: דבהג''א, בִּשְׂמֹאל; ובדאג''ה, בְּיָמִין (אַבּוּדַרְהַם וְסֵפֶר הַמּוּסָר). ‏
>
> When cutting one's nails one should not cut them in order. Rather one should start on the left hand with the ring finger - and then the index, pinkie, middle and thumb - 4,2,5,3,1. On the right hand one starts with index finger, then ring, thumb, middle and pinkie - 2,4,1,3,5.

However, many of the commentators bring the Ari z"l who said to ignore this idea, some even mentioning that he would laugh at people who cut their nails in the order.

> משנה ברורה ר״ס:ח‏
>   ח) לא יטול וכו' - בתשב"ץ כתוב שמהר"ם **לא דקדק בזה** וכ"כ על האר"י מ"מ יש ליזהר לכתחילה [מ"א]:‏
>
> מגן אברהם ר״ס:א‏
>   לא יטול אותן כסדרן. והאר"י היה מלעיג ע"ז ולא היה חושש לכך (הכונות) וכ"כ התשב"ץ סי' קנ"ד בשם מהר"מ מיהו יש ליזהר לכתחלה:‏
>
> כף החיים על שולחן ערוך אורח חיים ר״ס:יז:א‏
>   טוב) שם בהגה. וכשנוטל צפרניו לא יטול אותן כסדרן וכו' מיהו התשב"ץ סי' תקס"א כתב שמהר"ם ז"ל אינו חושש ליטול צפרניו כסדר. והביאו מט"מ שם וט"ז סק"ב. וכ"כ בשער הכו' דף ס"ב ע"ד דהאר"י ז"ל היה חותך וקוצץ צפרניו לכבוד שבת מידיו ומרגליו והיה קוצצן כסדרן ולא היה חושש ולא מקפיד אל אותו הסדר הנז' בס' אבודדהם בענין קציצת הצפרנים עכ"ל.‏

It would seem that there are sufficient opinions to rely on to have a non-Jew cut one's nails in any order they prefer.